# Need help deploying NextJS with prisma

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prisma, vercel

I deployed nextjs with prisma on vercel and planetscale.
I have four pages: admin get all quotes, paid quotes, completed and uncompleted quotes.

The main step I done was to create a fetcher function where I interact with the API routes. After creating the fetch functions, I get the into all the quotes pages. Inside the pages I filtered to get the relevant elements (paid, completed and uncompleted), and passed the filtered elements to a Quotes component that display the quotes on the relevant pages. The problem is that on the development, I have no issue. But on production I cannot get the data, upodate, delete it...

I created a separate file that intialise the prisma generate client...

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

const globalForPrisma = globalThis as unknown as { prisma: PrismaClient }

export const prisma =
  globalForPrisma.prisma || new PrismaClient()

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') globalForPrisma.prisma = prisma
```

The fetcher function that will be exported to the admin pages

```
//get all quotes
export const GetAllQuotesArray = async () => {
    const data = await fetch(`${baseURL}get-quotes`, { method: "GET" });
    const response = await data.json();
    return response;
    // const { data: allQuotes, isLoading: allQuotesLoading, mutate: mutateAllQuotes } = 
    // useSWR(`${baseURL}get-quotes`, fetcher);
    // return { allQuotes, allQuotesLoading, mutateAllQuotes };
}
```

The admin page that retrieve the quotes from the fetcher and pass it to the Quote component

```
  const [array, setArray ] = useState<IQuoteWithId[]>([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const allQuotesArray = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const result: IQuoteWithId[] = await GetAllQuotesArray();
    if (result) {
      setArray(result);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    allQuotesArray();
  }, []);
```

And this is the Quote component that display the quotes

```
const Quotes = ({ quotes, title, subtitle }: ComponentType): JSX.Element => {


  //set a state in order to re allocate the modified array when changed
  const [arrayQuotes, setArrayQuotes] = useState<IQuote[]>([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);

  
  useEffect(() => { 
    setArrayQuotes(quotes);
  }
  ,[loading]);


  

  
  
  const handleDeleteQuoteById = async (quoteId: string) => {
    //return the remaining quotes in the response and prefetch everything
    setLoading(true);
    await deleteQuoteById(quoteId);
    location.reload();
    setLoading(false);
  };
```

Before the git push, I linked the vercel to github repo. So any push is throw into production. One of the issues that I noticed is that all the pages and components used in here are client components. But when I use the Network tab I see no request...
I literally Don't know what to do now...

https://github.com/ddmihai/Chauffeurs
https://chauffeurs.vercel.app/admin-dashboard